# Can someone make my AWS S3 bill explode?

Tags: amazon-s3

If I have some file uploaded on AWS S3 and it has a public url, can someone make my AWS bill explode by automatically downloading this file over and over again?

Comment: I think yes, if you have a 1GB file and was downloaded 100K times within the month, total cost will be 9K USD. Here's the S3 pricing for data transfer: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing

Comment: This is the most unsatisfying but probably truthful answer I ever got.

Comment: If for some reason you're deciding to have public access to a file on S3, I would suggest also add a budget specifically to S3 costs so you'll be notified on price jumps. Also consider that it is true in theory, I think considering the probability of someone just abusing your S3 public access for their on amusement, while possible, it's still improbable.